# Какие HTML теги моветон?

Tags: html, css, html5, вёрстка

Какие HTML теги при оформлении css считается моветон ?

Comment: div и span в неумеренных количествах вместо подходящих семантичных тегов

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Во-первых, не стоит использовать все элементы, помеченные в спецификации как устаревшие или даже исключённые из неё. Это `b`, `i`, `u`, `strike`, `big`, `small`, `font` и некоторые другие.

Также есть некоторые элементы, которые хотя и имеют некоторое дефаултное оформление, обрели свою семантику. Использовать их чисто ради оформления неправильно, но использование по прямому назначению вполне оправдано:

- `br` - перевод строки. Идеально подойдёт для строк внутри стихов или песен, но НЕ подойдёт для создания пустой строки между куплетами - вместо этого можно, например, оборачивать сами куплеты в `p`.
- `hr` - горизонтальная линия. В книгах иногда внутри глав встречаются `***` как разделитель меньший, чем глава - вот на его роль hr отлично подходит. Более спорное использование - между самими главами (по сути дублирует заголовки) и между куплетами песни.
- `em` и `strong` - смысловое акцентирование слов. Их *не следует*  использовать просто ради курсива и жирного шрифта. А вот курсив в этом тексте у сочетания "не следует" вполне логично сделать через em.
- `mark` - выделение совпадений, например, подсветить поисковую фразу в результатах поиска. А не просто жёлтый фон.
- `s` - неактуальная информация. Например, во время скидок можно поместить в него старую цену. А просто что-то зачеркнуть надо через css.
- `ins` и `del` - вставленный и удалённый текст - некое версионирование. Собственно, кроме версионирования ничего в голову и не приходит.

Сейчас становится популярным использовать тег `i` для иконок. Вообще-то не уверен как на это смотрит стандарт, но почему бы и нет. Может со временем это там закрепится.

Ещё есть интересный тег `plaintext` - он никогда не был в спецификации, но обладает удивительной особенностью - всё, что идёт после его открытия становится просто текстом. На страницах я его никогда не использовал, но он просто идеален для вывода текстовой информации в новом окне, так что довольно часто я его использую в сниппетах которые запускаю в своём браузере. Но формально его использовать не стоит :)

PS: Вообще пришло в голову, что презентационные теги подходят для wysiwyg-редакторов, поскольку там семантика неизвестна. С другой стороны, всё то же самое можно сделать просто через классы на span'ах.

Comment: 1. В стандарте или на аналогичных сайтах. Можно на mdn. 2. Не вижу опечатки... 3. Через css стилизовать span, div или что там у тебя есть. 4. Дополнил ответ.

Comment: Имеется в виду default. Оформление по умолчанию - то, которое прописано в браузерных стилях для этих тегов.

Comment: спасибо что потратили время и ответили на вопросы :)

Comment: Вот как раз уж лучше тег b, чем span.class=bold. Семантики и там и там ноль, но первое в миллион раз короче и понятнее.

Answer (score 0):

Одни "плохие теги" попросту отвечают за внешнее представление элемента (как тег ), и их можно заменить на нечто более значимое, либо использовать вместо них CSS. Другие же могут не только определять визуальное представление, но и быть к тому же излишне громоздки (как тег `<font>`) или ужасно пагубны для удобства использования веб-страницы (как тег `<blink>`).

Теги
Ниже приводится большинство общих тегов, у которых есть лучшая альтернатива:

`<b>` отображает текст жирным шрифтом. Вместо него можно использовать тег `<strong>`, который добавляет элементу дополнительное значение (усиленное выделение), либо, если необходимо просто отобразить текст жирным шрифтом, соответствующее свойство CSS выполняет ту же работу.
`<i>` отображает текст курсивом. Использование тега `<em>` также добавляет дополнительную информацию (выделение), а для обычной визуализации подойдет соответствующее свойство CSS.

`<big>` увеличивает размер отображаемого текста. Если текст используется в качестве заголовка, то лучше использовать теги заголовков (`<h1>, <h2>` и т.д.), которые именно для этого и предназначены, а для простого визуального выделения следует использовать свойство CSS font-size, которое предоставляет больший контроль над страницей.
`<small>` уменьшает размер отображаемого текста. Опять же для этого лучше использовать свойство CSS font-size.
`<hr>` создает горизонтальную линию. Тем не менее, в веб-странице, основывающейся на CSS, использование этого тега несколько необычно. Для этого вполне подойдет свойство CSS border-top или border-bottom, либо, в крайнем случае, старый добрый тег изображения сделает это лучше.

Ко всем перечисленным тегам последние стандарты HTML относятся достаточно лояльно, однако эти теги ничего не добавляют к значению контента, что обязаны делать "хорошие теги". Все эти "пустышки" могли бы быть более полезны, но они не приносят и вреда, в отличие от следующих "вредин":

`<u>` в свое время использовался для подчеркивания текста. Так получилось, что подчеркнутый текст прочно ассоциируется со ссылками. Именно поэтому этот тег давно умер, и именно поэтому крайне не желательно иметь в тексте подчеркнутые участки, не являющиеся ссылками.
`<center>` использовался для центрирования одного элемента относительно другого. Свойство CSS text-align имеет не только значение center, но и left, right и justify.
`<layer>` аналогичен тегу `<div>`, однако работает он только в старых версиях браузера Netscape и потому совершенно бесполезен.
`<blink>` или `<marquee>`. Наше твердое "Нет!". Они должны были делать мигающий текст, однако из-за ограниченной поддержки вскоре превратились в дурную шутку.
`<font>` использовался для определения имени, размера и цвета шрифта элементов. Этот тег снискал репутацию злого гения мира тегов. Старые сайты (и даже некоторые новые) подобно оспинами буквально испещрены тегами `<font>`. Большинство из них обязаны своему появлению различным программам автоматизации создания сайтов, вставляющие тег `<font>` вокруг всякого элемента, размер или цвет которого изменяет автор. Так как этот тег приходится вставлять вокруг каждого появления элемента (скажем, каждый раз, как используется элемент `<p>`), то при помощи свойств CSS это можно сделать при помощи одной маленькой строки кода и применить ее ко всему сайту. Такой способ не только делает код веб-страницы меньше, но и позволяет при модифицировании стиля изменить всего одну строку, а не отыскивать все теги `<font>` в коде всех веб-страниц. Тег `<font>` и неуместное использование таблиц – две наиболее частые причины распухания кода веб-страниц.

[источник](https://msiter.ru/tutorials/html-srednego-urovnya/plokhie-tegi)

Comment: Боже, какого года эта статья, если в ней всерьёз упоминается NN! =)